# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in HomeController#index Couldn't find User with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, ruby-on-rails-5

ERROR: when logout.

I'm trying to display `_admin_user_header` partial using an `if` statement for when 'admin' is logged_in:

Extracted from: `_header` partial.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex justify-content-end">
  <% if(current_user && current_user.role == 'admin') %>      <== this 
    <%= render partial: 'admin_user_header' %>                <== 2 lines 
  <% elsif(logged_in?) %>
    <%= render partial: 'registered_user_header' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render partial: 'anonymous_user_header' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Doing `<% if(current_user && current_user.role == 'admin') %>` apparently works, but when I try to logout from the current_user account, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in HomeController#index

Couldn't find User with 'id'=
Extracted source (around line #25):

23      end
24
25      @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
26   end
27
28   def ensure_authenticated

Rails.root: 
/Users/dangerrg/Documents/....

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:25:in `current_user'
app/views/application/_header.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_application__header_html_erb__900908384298268245_70228604326660'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___299989914533477205_70228570235680'
```

I've checked other posts answers with a similar problem, looking for solutions, and I tried different ways to accomplish this, but no success yet.

I also check my DB in the Rails console and all users have and `:id` with its respective value assigned to it.

In **application_controller.rb**

```
...

 helper_method :logged_in?, :current_user

 def logged_in?
   session[:user_id].present?
 end

...

 def current_user
   if(@current_user.present?)
     return @current_user
   end

   @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
 end

...
```

In **home_controler.rb** this is the only method:

```
 def index
   @tips = Tip.most_recent
 end
```

I'll really appreciate any help on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_user` will work only if user logged in. After logout it clears out session[:user_id]. That's why you can not find a user.

```
User.find(nil)
```

Before you call current user method that queries DB try to check that session[:user_id] present. That will work:

```
if(logged_in? && current_user && current_user.role == 'admin')
```

or

```
def current_user
  return unless logged_id?

  if(@current_user.present?)
    return @current_user
  end

  @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
end
```

I think the best option here is to wrap render in `if(logged_in?)` statement:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex justify-content-end">
  <% if(logged_in?) %>
    <% if(current_user && current_user.role == 'admin') %>      
      <%= render partial: 'admin_user_header' %>                
    <% else %>
      <%= render partial: 'registered_user_header' %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render partial: 'anonymous_user_header' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I used the `wrap render in if(logged_in?)`, so, all the changes are made in just one file, it worked perfectly well. Thanks a lot.